# Invert bitwise operation on dataframe's columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am experiencing an unexpected behaviour on panda dataframe. Maybe someone can explain it to me.

I want to select a row based on multiple conditions happening simultaneously. 
Example:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'a': [1, 2, 1, 2], 'b': [5, 6, 7, 8]} 
d = pd.DataFrame(data)

   a  b
0  1  5
1  2  6
2  1  7
3  2  8

d[(d['a']==1) & (d['b']==5)]
```

This works as expected and returns

```
   a  b
0  1  5
```

However, the exclusion version does not work.

```
d[(d['a']!=1) & (d['b']!=5)]

   a  b
1  2  6
3  2  8
```

Whereas as I would obviously expect

```
   a  b
1  2  6
2  1  7
3  2  8
```

What's going on here and how do I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're applying the same operation on the *inverted* boolean arrays, but what you really need, is the [de Morgan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) of the operation. So either take the bitwise `OR` of the inverted arrays, as in Jezrael's answer or (slightly modifying your example with the bitwise `AND`) apply a bitwise `NOT` to the result:

```
df[~((df['a']==1) & (df['b']==5))]

   a  b
1  2  6
2  1  7
3  2  8
```

---

That is, in jezrael's answer you have:

```
not(A & B) ≠ not(A) & not(B) #wrong
not(A & B) = not(A) | not(B)
```

And in this answer where we're just producing the same as above by taking the `NOT` of the operation.

Comment: THANKS! That's exactly what I was thinking, but df[!((df['a']==1) & (df['b']==5))] or df[not((df['a']==1) & (df['b']==5))] didn't work!

Comment: That is because you should be applying `bitwise operators`, and that is not @Vaaal88

Answer (score 1):

Use `|` for bitwise `OR` instead `&` for bitwise AND:

```
df = d[(d['a']!=1) | (d['b']!=5)]
print (df)
   a  b
1  2  6
2  1  7
3  2  8
```

Comment: both answers are correct. I find it slightly more intuitive the other one. Thanks though